# Need help identifying this star wars set

Tags: star-wars, set-identification

[image]Need help identifying this old star wars set, trying to rebuild my LEGO sets!

Comment: and who can identify the rug?

Comment: Looks like a nice City play scene rug ;)

Answer (score 9):

The parts are from the [8016 LEGO Star Wars Hyena Droid Bomber](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=8016-1#T=S&O=%7B"ii":1%7D) from 2009.
[image]

Comment: Aah, the old days :)